# "Failed to get a list of devices: 'Forbidden'", when list new printers on Kubuntu20.04

Tags: permissions, 20.04, kubuntu, printing, adduser

I installed a fresh Kubuntu-20.04, and created the first user(jacky) by means of the installer of Kubuntu, then I created the second user(leon), by using cmd-line tool "`adduser`", and adding it into the group "`root`" and "`libvirt`".

Both of these two users can login KDE and do things normally, but only jacky can setup printers of the system. When I login with `leon` and open "`System Setting` -> `Printers`", and click the button "Click here to add a new printer", I always get a error msg:

> Failed to get a list of devices: 'Forbidden'

in a poped-up dialog box "Add a New Printer".
If with the user `jacky` do so, no error occurs.

I guess these two users are different, but I don't know what difference is there and how fix it.
Any hints?

Please Forgive my English!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding your user "leon" to group "lpadmin" and log out and re-login again. I can't test this at the moment.

I'm getting the same error in openSUSE 15.2 KDE for my only user. In the journalD log, I see `kde-add-printer   libkcups: CUPS-Get-Devices last error: 1025 Forbidden`. I'm guessing it's the same for you?

Comment: Yes! You got it! But the exact group name is "lpadmin" instead of "lp". Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want the new user to have the ability to invoke root permissions with `sudo`.

Don't add the user to the `root` group.  Add it to sudoers.

The correct command to add a user to "sudoers" is: `sudo adduser <username> sudo`.

You need to run this command as root, or from another user that has sudo privileges.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I added the second user(leon) into the group "sudo", but it don't work.